Multi Ubuntu version targetting from single dockerfile
I am using a single Dockerfile to build images for different Ubuntu versions. Those images are then used in CI to build software targeting those different Ubuntu versions.
Sometimes, there are of course some differences between Ubuntu versions, e.g. I'm installing different compilers. The code I use looks something like this
FROM $baseimage AS base_image
ARG distro
ARG ${distro}=" "
...
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-${focal:+10}${jammy:+14} 10

And this used to work just fine but it doesn't seem to work anymore.
First of all, this uses simple bash functionality. To reproduce locally simple do in the terminal
$export bar="BAR"
$export $bar=" "
$echo "test ${BAR:+barr} ${FOO:-notfooo}"
test barr notfooo

This works just fine in the terminal, but the Dockerfile doesn't work like this anymore.
So here's a minimal image to reproduce with full Dockerfile and build commands
Dockerfile:
ARG baseimage
ARG distro
ARG ${distro}=" "

FROM $baseimage AS base_image
ARG distro
ARG ${distro}=" "

RUN echo "arg is ${distro}" > /test.log
RUN echo "distro is ${focal:+Focal}${jammy:+Jammy} ${focal:-not Focal}${jammy:-not Jammy}" >> /test.log

CMD sleep infinity

build commands
baseimage='ubuntu:focal'
distro='focal'
docker build . -t testimage:${distro} --build-arg distro=${distro} --build-arg baseimage=${baseimage} -f Dockerfile --target base_image

In this case, when using focal as test argument, I'd expect the log file contents to be
arg is focal
distro is Focal not Jammy

However, instead it's
arg is focal
distro is  not Focalnot Jammy

I don't know what exactly changed to make it stop working, but I assume a recent docker upgrade (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 here for building those images). But this used to work, and now it doesn't anymore.
Does anyone know how to get this functionality back?

I'm a little surprised to see a variable expansion on the left-hand side of ARG, though syntactically I understand how it would work.  If you RUN env, do you see the variable set?  Can you use a shell if or case statement instead of relying on these extra per-distribution variables?

@DavidMaze no, with RUN env > env.log I only see the distro variable set, not the focal or jammy ones

@markp-fuso, the ARG command in Dockerfile sets env variables for the build duration and I populate the distro one via argument in the build command. so the ARG distro command leads to the distro env var being populated with focal in this example.

@markp-fuso Not quite. I have ARG distro which succesfully sets distro variable to focal as value.
And then there is ARG ${distro}=" " which seemingly does nothing. Conceptually it is meant to create a variable with the name of the value of the variable distro, i.e. a variable named focal which is to be set to the value " ". This used to work just fine until at least early May when I last built a set of containers with this code.

The core Docker build engine has seen one or two rewrites in recent memory.  Is it possible that maybe the Docker BuildKit engine is treating ARG ${distro}=... differently?  (You may be able to set an environment variable DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 in your host build environment.)

@DavidMaze Thank you very much!! With DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 it works as it used again.
